# i got a syntax err in mysql(js)(Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR)

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord, discord.js

i'm doing a option to change each server prefix in discord, i'm doing it with mysql

code:

```
  var values = {
  prefixcol: arg[1],
  serverid: message.guild.id
};

  var sqlaa = "INSERT INTO prefix (prefixcol, serverid) VALUES ?";
  con.query(sqlaa, values, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log("1 record inserted")
});
```

and i got a err:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`prefixcol` = '1', `serverid` = '434013824207814706'' at line 1

Comment: What are the types of your `prefixcol` and `serverid` columns? Because your JavaScript values are strings. Check if a String can be inserted in both columns.

Comment: Not 100% sure about javacript, but every other implementation of parameterized queries I've encountered requires once placeholder per parameter, and for the general clause syntax to be followed. i..e I'd expect something more like `INSERT INTO prefix (prefixcol, serverid) VALUES (?, ?)`

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with `node` v8.9.4 and `mysql` v2.15.0 and you need to surround the ? with parenthesis

```
var sqlaa = "INSERT INTO prefix (prefixcol, serverid) VALUES (?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed SQL Statement. Corresponding to your Code it would be

```
var values = {
  prefixcol: arg[1],
  serverid: message.guild.id
};

  var sqlaa = "INSERT INTO prefix (prefixcol, serverid) VALUES (?,?)";
  con.query(sqlaa, values, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log("1 record inserted")
});
```

That's cause you enter 2 values so you need to insert 2